# Define two variables at the same line

Tags: python-2.7, user-input

How to take **multiple inputs** using **raw_input** in python 2.7 ?
I mean, writing the code below in single line:

```
n= raw_input("name :")
pref = raw_input("preference :")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the variable with comma separated at the same line.

```
n, pref = raw_input("name :"), raw_input("preference :")
```

Comment: Thank you for help